# Is a high prediction performance of allocated treatment evidence for lack of unobserved confounding?

Tags: predictive-models, causality, confounding, random-allocation

#### Example

Say *Investigator 1* is looking to investigate the effect of fish consumption (a binary variable $A$ indicating whether they eat or do not eat fish) on cardiovascular health (a continuous variable $Y$). They have a set of observed variables, $\boldsymbol{L}$, that cause both the exposure $A$ and outcome $Y$, i.e. they are confounders. These variables can be for instance, socioeconomic status, proximity to the shore, nationality of parents, allergies, etc. Under these assumptions, *Investigator 1* adjusts for $\boldsymbol{L}$ in their analysis. They find that fish consumption improves cardiovascular health.

However:

- A colleague, *Investigator 2*, says that there is a problem with the analysis of *Investigator 1*, noting that there are known variables in the literature that confound the relationship and that they did not adjust for, i.e. there are unobserved confounders.
- *Investigator 1* says that these variables should be inconsequential, as they are able to correctly predict 99% of subjects' fish consumption using the set $\boldsymbol{L}$ as predictors.
- *Investigator 2* replies that some of the variables in the literature are rare-events unrelated to variables $\boldsymbol{L}$, that appear in about 1% of cases, but that their impact on the outcome is huge. So unobserved confounding is still a relevant threat.

---

#### Question

**Is the reasoning from *Investigator 1* correct?**

1. Were it not for the information that *Investigator 2* has brought, would they be correct if they were in a specific field where effects are known to be small?
2. Are there counterexamples where even perfect prediction of treatment allocation cannot rule out the presence of unobserved confounding?